# Как подключить стили дочерней темы Вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создала дочернюю тему в вордпресс.

Использовала плагин [Child Theme Configurator](http://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator).

Хочу отредактировать в ней стили. Не получается.

Знаю, что есть гугл и гора инфы в нём. Читаю, применяю, не помогает.

На что обратить внимание, чтобы разобраться, и заработало, как надо?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно "не получается"?

Comment: Не получается подключить стили дочерней темы так, чтобы изменения в стилях отображались в браузере.
Т.е. беру нужный для редактирования документ из папки assets, вношу в него изменения, сохраняю. В браузере жму ctrl+F5 и ничего не меняется по сравнению с родительской темой.

Comment: Если задать стили через !important к примеру `body {
    background-color: red !important;
}` тоже не никаких изменений, ошибки в консоле браузера есть?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нет.
 !important к примеру body { background-color: red !important; } - не дает изменений.

Comment: В какой файл вы вносите изменения?из какой `assets` папки? По скрину что скинули видно что подключен только файл style.css в папке дочерней темы и больше ничего.

Comment: Больше ничего не надо подключать. Нужно просто прописывать нужные стили  в файл и не забывать про основы css - наследование и каскадирование.

Comment: "По скрину что скинули видно что подключен только файл style.css в папке дочерней темы и больше ничего." Есть она (смотрите самый первый скрин). Продублировала её в дочернюю из родительской и пытаюсь вносить в ней изменения для нужных классов. С  !important тоже не работает.

Comment: SeVlad 
Вроде бы так и делаю. 
Или имеется в виду, что вносить изменения можно только в сам style.css дочерней темы?
изменения в нём тоже ничего не дают.

Comment: Именно в файл стилей дочки. Если "не дают". то 2 варианта - не правильные правила или кеш.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно править файл style.css в дочерней темы, если хотите дополнительно править стили в др. файлах css, то для начало их нужно подключить, добавьте код в function.php в функцию
 chld_thm_cfg_parent_css()  `'your_style_name'` поменяйте на название файла

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style_name_1', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . '/assets/your_style_name.css');
```

Comment: В .css дочерней темы и пытаюсь править.
Про другие .css, то они уже были подключены в functions.php родительской темы.

Comment: Добавила <wp_enqueue_style( 'style_name_1', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . '/assets/your_style_name.css');>
в functions.php дочерней. Получилось, что они подключились ещё раз и переопределили без изменений те, что были подключены в родительской.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что стили родительской подключаются позже стилей дочерней. Поэтому изменения в дочерней не отображаются в браузере.

Comment: добавьте скрин из консоли, какие стили вообще подключаются. Пример
http://joxi.ru/V2Vbya6HdBoGa2

Comment: http://joxi.ru/DmBM7eahJWdaKr

Comment: Приследуемые мной стили пишутся инлайново.
http://joxi.ru/DmBM7eahJWdaKr

Comment: Это точно скрин с сайта? Маловато стилей, даже дефолтных нет.Отключите кэш http://joxi.ru/nAyvPBpTg9zWer обновите сайт при включенной консоли и сделайте скрин снова.

Comment: Ну да. Это так http://joxi.ru/zANOQZNCvyJMPr

Comment: Не надо писать этого бреда. Файл стилей уже подключен.